# Scrapy code error - inconsistent use of tabs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

when I try to run this code, I get this error 
help me with this

> File "E:\pycode\testscrap1\testscrap1\spiders\quotes.py", line 11
>       h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
>                                                              ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
import scrapy        

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'quotes'
  allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
  start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

  def parse(self, response):
    h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
    tags = response.xpath('//*[@class="tag-item"]/a/text()').extract()

    yield {'H1 TAG' : h1_tag, 'Tags' : tags}
```

Comment: see that error .....it's indentation problem.

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces when indenting your code (exactly as the error message says...)

Comment: I used to get the same error. ıf you write the codes in another text editor, and then run in another one. that may cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of spaces and tabs. Just remove all tabs in your code and use spaces instead, or vice versa. I used only spaces instead of tabs and it fixed.